# Google My Business API: Getting 404 Error

Tags: google-oauth, google-my-business-api, oauth2-playground

I recently signed up for Google My Business and I'm trying to use OAUTH playground in order to make API requests.

Here's my info:

Project name
SalesForce

Project ID
salesforce-273422

Project number
310709897826

I'm running into issues with the google my business API. I am trying to follow instructions listed here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/basic-setup#make-simple-http-request in order to make some request to the My Business API.

My client ID is 310709897826-i0qmgqucprqug6gmtb32oualp4q7k374.apps.googleusercontent.com and I am still unable to make any successful requests with the oauth playground, i get a 404 not found when i try to list all accounts. Is there any configuration that is incorrect or that I'm missing?

Please help! I'm unsure what's wrong.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, open the playground [https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground], from the top right side, follow the pic below and copy paste your clientId, make sure you have selected "client-side".
[image]

Then, on the left side, eneter https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage  and press the button "Authorise Apis"

[image]

Next, you are asked to sign in with your client username and password, so after signing in, you are  given about an hour or so to work in playground:
[image]

Comment: i got to this point and authorized successfully, but when trying to do `https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/locations` i get 404 :(

Comment: @user151496 would you please the complete error message or even a screenshot of the error

Comment: well, it was just 404 ... regular 404 you get when resource is not found. anyways, i found the problem, it was that "google my business" api was enabled but "google my business information api" was not. i have no idea do you need to enable 6-8 separate business apis in order to use them, why not just one business api

Comment: @user151496, unfortunately yes, you should activate all APIs separately. that was why I asked you to share the exact error, because sometimes it gives you the link to activate. Anyway open your https://console.cloud.google.com and log in to your account and from API and Services you can see the list of activated APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the "OAuth Client ID" in the OAuth 2.0 Configuration tab? with

OAuth flow:Client side
Use your own OAuth credentials: (mark with a tick)
OAuth Client ID: (enter your oauth client id)

In step 1: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage
In step 2: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts